# Ecto Queryable not implemented for Phoenix module

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm following the Programming Phoenix 1.4 tutorial and have run into a problem where I'm being told `Ecto Queryable` is not implemented for a given module but I can't tell why. There's another question similar to this on SO but it has a simple answer that does not apply to my case.

I have this code in my `lib/rumbl/accounts/user.ex` file:

```ex
defmodule Rumbl.Accounts.User do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "users" do
    field :name, :string
    field :username, :string

    timestamps()
  end
end
```

This is the code in my `lib/rumbl/accounts/accounts.ex` file:

```ex
defmodule Rumbl.Accounts do
  @moduledoc """
  The Accounts context.
  """

  alias Rumbl.Accounts.User
  alias Rumbl.Repo

  def get_user(id) do
    Repo.get(User, id)
  end

  def get_user!(id) do
    Repo.get!(User, id)
  end

  def get_user_by(params) do
    Repo.get_by(User, params)
  end

  def list_users do
    Repo.all(User)
  end
end
```

However, when I call `Rumbl.Accounts.list_users` from my `UserController`, I get the following error:

```ex
** (Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol Ecto.Queryable not implemented for Rumbl.Accounts.User, the given module does not provide a schema. This protocol is implemented for: Atom, BitString, Ecto.Query, Ecto.SubQuery, Tuple
```

I don't get the same error when I run the same queries in `mix -S iex`.

This may be an error in the code the book suggests since it's in beta, but I can't for the life of me figure out what was wrong. In the other SO post the user had forgotten to alias `Rumbl.Accounts.User`, but that's clearly not the case for me.

Comment: What happens when you call `Rumbl.Repo.all(Rumbl.Accounts.User)` in `iex`?

Comment: No error, it works fine in `iex`.

Comment: Yes, that worked! If you make that an answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct and should work without issues. The problem may be solved by cleaning the build files and recompiling your code:

```
$ mix clean
$ mix compile
```